# How to save the context execution of a newly created user thread, Linux 64 to structure in C?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am trying to implement a new user thread management library similar to the original pthread but only in C. Only the context switch should be assembler.

Looks like I am missing something fundamentally. 
I have the following structure for the context execution:

```
enter code here

struct exec_ctx {
uint64_t rbp;
uint64_t r15;
uint64_t r14;
uint64_t r13;
uint64_t r12;
uint64_t r11;
uint64_t r10;
uint64_t r9;
uint64_t r8;
uint64_t rsi;
uint64_t rdi;
uint64_t rdx;
uint64_t rcx;
uint64_t rbx;
uint64_t rip;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

I create new thread structure and I should put the registers into the mentioned variables, part of the context execution structure. How may I do it on C? Everywhere only talks about setcontext, getcontext, but this is not the case here.

Also, the only hint I received is I need to have some kind of dump stack function into the create function.... not sure how to do it. Please advise where can I read further/how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

I started with:

```
 char *stack;
 stack = malloc(StackSize); 
 if (!stack)
     return -1;

 *(uint64_t *)&stack[StackSize -  8] = (uint64_t)stop;
 *(uint64_t *)&stack[StackSize - 16] = (uint64_t)f;
 pet_thread->ctx.rip = (uint64_t)&stack[StackSize - 16];
 pet_thread->thread_state = Ready;
```

This is how I put a pointer to the thread function on the top of the stack in order to call the thread more easily.

Comment: You can't directly access any of the registers in C.  You'll have use assembler to save the values into the structure, and to recover the values from the structure — as well as in the context switch.  IMNSHO, applying `__attribute__((packed))` to a structure consisting only of `uint64_t` shows a lack of understanding of packed and `uint64_t`, too.

Comment: Another problem is that you *must* also save the SSE/MMX/FP registers - these are better done lazily as otherwise you'd pay extra overhead, but again this requires kernel support.

Comment: All in all, forget about this mess and use `getcontext/setcontext` instead.

Comment: Yes, `getcontext/setcontext` is exactly what your are looking for. In particular, you seem to assume that all machines in the world have the same hardware registers and names. CPUs all different, models evolve in time and have more and more registers. If you'd do follow that yourself this would be a maintenance nightmare. Why repeat the work that so many people already have put much effort in?

Comment: This is a special assignment at school with educational purpose. It should be done in this way. Otherwise I would go for getcontext/setcontext

Comment: I was told the context switch should be the only assembler plus abort to stack function. The context happens by simply pushing the current context on the stack, switching to another one and popping the execution context which resides there

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need to save all the registers. Since your context switch is implemented as a function, any register that the ABI defines as "caller saved" or "clobbered" you can safely leave out. The code generated by the C compiler will assume it might change.

Since this is a school assignment I will not give you the code to do this. I will give you the outline.

Your function needs to both save the registers to the struct for the outgoing micro-thread *and* load the register for the incoming micro-thread. The reason is that you have logically always have one register set "in effect". So your function needs two arguments, the struct for the outgoing micro-thread and the one for the incoming.

Those two arguments are stored in two registers. Those two you do not need to save. So your code should have the following structure (assuming your structure, which, as I said, is too complete):

```
# save context
mov [rdi], rbp
add 8, rdi
...

#load context
mov rbp, [rsi]
add 8, rsi
...
```

If you place that in a separate .S file, you'll make sure that the C compiler will not add anything or optimize anything.

This is not the cleanest or most efficient solution, but it is the simplest.